# T-SQL with three sub queries causing long execution time, any combination of 2 is near instant

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following T-SQL:

```
SELECT TOP (1) *, (
    SELECT COUNT(result_id)
    FROM Result
    JOIN TestRun ON (TestRun.test_run_id = Result.test_run_id)
    JOIN RegressionRun ON (RegressionRun.regression_run_id = TestRun.regression_run_id)
    WHERE RegressionRun.regression_run_id = RR.regression_run_id AND result_type_id = 31
)  a, (
    SELECT COUNT(result_id)
    FROM Result
    JOIN TestRun ON (TestRun.test_run_id = Result.test_run_id)
    JOIN RegressionRun ON (RegressionRun.regression_run_id = TestRun.regression_run_id)
    WHERE RegressionRun.regression_run_id = RR.regression_run_id AND result_type_id = 32
)  b, (
    SELECT COUNT(result_id)
    FROM Result
    JOIN TestRun ON (TestRun.test_run_id = Result.test_run_id)
    JOIN RegressionRun ON (RegressionRun.regression_run_id = TestRun.regression_run_id)
    WHERE RegressionRun.regression_run_id = RR.regression_run_id AND result_type_id = 33
)  c
FROM RegressionRun RR
ORDER BY regression_run_id DESC
```

Columns a, b and c are executing almost identical sub queries, the only difference being the result_type_id comparison in the WHERE clause.

If I run this query it takes ~10 seconds to complete.

If I remove any one of the sub query columns (a, b or c) it takes a few milliseconds to complete.

Why is adding the third sub query causing such a significant increase in performance?

Other possibly useful information:

- The RegressionRun table has ~300 rows, TestRun has ~600 rows and Result has ~5 million rows
- Issue is 100% reproducible
- The SQL Server has plenty of spare resource and nothing else is using it when I am executing these queries
- Using SQL Server 2017

Any suggestions as to why this may be occurring and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Investigate actual execution plan. Probably server switches join operation type from HASH to LOOP or backwards, or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tryed not to change your query greatly.

Try this variant

```
SELECT *,
  (
      SELECT COUNT(result_id)
      FROM Result
      JOIN TestRun ON (TestRun.test_run_id = Result.test_run_id)
      JOIN RegressionRun ON (RegressionRun.regression_run_id = TestRun.regression_run_id)
      WHERE RegressionRun.regression_run_id = RR.regression_run_id AND result_type_id = 31
  )  a,
  (
      SELECT COUNT(result_id)
      FROM Result
      JOIN TestRun ON (TestRun.test_run_id = Result.test_run_id)
      JOIN RegressionRun ON (RegressionRun.regression_run_id = TestRun.regression_run_id)
      WHERE RegressionRun.regression_run_id = RR.regression_run_id AND result_type_id = 32
  )  b,
  (
      SELECT COUNT(result_id)
      FROM Result
      JOIN TestRun ON (TestRun.test_run_id = Result.test_run_id)
      JOIN RegressionRun ON (RegressionRun.regression_run_id = TestRun.regression_run_id)
      WHERE RegressionRun.regression_run_id = RR.regression_run_id AND result_type_id = 33
  )  c
FROM
  (
    SELECT TOP (1) *
    FROM RegressionRun
    ORDER BY regression_run_id DESC
  ) RR
```

Or you can use `OUTER APPLY`

```
SELECT RR.*,C.a,C.b,C.c
FROM
  (
    SELECT TOP (1) *
    FROM RegressionRun
    ORDER BY regression_run_id DESC
  ) RR
OUTER APPLY
  (
      SELECT
        COUNT(CASE WHEN result_type_id = 31 THEN result_id END) a,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN result_type_id = 32 THEN result_id END) b,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN result_type_id = 33 THEN result_id END) c
      FROM Result
      JOIN TestRun ON (TestRun.test_run_id = Result.test_run_id)
      JOIN RegressionRun ON (RegressionRun.regression_run_id = TestRun.regression_run_id)
      WHERE RegressionRun.regression_run_id = RR.regression_run_id
  ) C
```

Comment: Same issue, query takes ages to complete. If I remove any one sub query its near instant.

Comment: @Elluko - Try the second variant with OUTER APPLY. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the performance is varying so greatly based on the number of correlated subqueries you include.  But we should pause for a moment and ask why you even need correlated subqueries.  We can try to rephrase your query using direct joins with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    t1.*, t2.a, t2.b, t2.c
FROM RegressionRun t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        rr.regression_run_id,
        SUM(CASE WHEN result_type_id = 31 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS a,
        SUM(CASE WHEN result_type_id = 32 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS b,
        SUM(CASE WHEN result_type_id = 33 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c
    FROM RegressionRun rr
    INNER JOIN TestRun tr
        ON rr.regression_run_id = tr.regression_run_id
    INNER JOIN Result r
        ON tr.test_run_id = r.test_run_id
    GROUP BY
        rr.regression_run_id
) t2
    ON t1.regression_run_id = t2.regression_run_id;
```